# Which is the best way to develop an iphone app similar to existing app?

Tags: ios

Hi am going to develop an iphone app which is similar to the app which is already availble in appstore .I would like to know whether i can start the app from scratch  or i can customize the code of existing app.I need to know the best way for creating this type of app. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start from scratch unless the developer of the other app shares the source code with you. You cant just pick an app from app store and edit it.

Comment: Yes i agree . Also the developer is ready to share the code.I would like to know the easiest way.

Comment: @Umarajendran, If developer is sharing the code, what is the problem you are facing with the code? Any specific issues? Either you can just copy the necessary classes from that project or you can rename that project and modify according to your requirement right?

Comment: Yes but my doubt is will it take more time to analyse the existing code than creating a code from scratch

Comment: @Umarajendran, That depends on the code. Cant predict that without seeing that. If it is a simple code, you can just use it. If it has too many complicated features, start from scratch.